# Type mismatch when receiving user input in python

Tags: python

I running the following program as a teaching exercise:

```
height = input("State your height : ")
age = input("State your age : ")

if type(height) == float and type(age) == int:
    print(f"You're {height} m tall and {age} years old")
else:
    print("\n You've made a mistake ! Enter your data again .")
    height = input("State your height : ")
    age = input("State your age : ")
    print(f"You're {height} m tall and {age} years old")
```

With the following inputs and output :

```
State your height : 2.2
State your age : 10

 You've made a mistake ! Enter your data again .
State your height : 2.2
State your age : 10
You're 2.2 m tall and 10 years old
```

I gave the correct type of values (a float for the height and int for the age) so the 'if' block should be executed yet Python values the expression as false and goes to the 'else' block. What am I doing wrong in this program?

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, `input` always returns a string, regardless of what the data "looks like". You need to manually parse `height` and `age` as `float`s and `int`s.

```
height = float(input("State your height : "))
age = int(input("State your age : "))
```

This will cause `ValueError`s to be raised if they enter invalid data, which means that instead of an `if` check, you'd use a `try`/`catch`:

```
try:
    height = float(input("State your height : "))
    age = int(input("State your age : "))
except ValueError:
    print("\n You've made a mistake ! Enter your data again .")
```

Now, you just need to add a loop in there to ask multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate type using `isinstance(height, int)`.

However the problem is that the input is string so you have to cast it by surrounding with `int()` or `float()`.

Cast it like this:

```
def get_input():
    height = int(input("State your height : "))
    age = float(input("State your age : "))
    return height, age


is_input_valid = False

while not is_input_valid:
    try:
        height, age = get_input()
        print(f"You're {height} m tall and {age} years old")
        is_input_valid = True
    except ValueError:
        print("\n You've made a mistake ! Enter your data again .")
```